# What is 'Transcendental algebraic geometry'?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

What is 'Transcendental algebraic geometry'? Could you give me some good references in this field? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Transcendental Algebraic Geometry is the study of the algebraic geometry of a variety defined over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$ by concentrating on its undelying structure as a holomorphic manifold or variety.
This allows one to study the variety through the powerful tools of topology, analysis and differential geometry like : characteristic  classes, elliptic partial differential equations, Kähler structure, ...
Serre wrote a remarkable article (always quoted as GAGA!) giving a very precise functorial correspondence between a projective algebraic variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$ and the corresponding complex analytic  variety $X^{an}$: [here](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1956__6_/AIF_1956__6__1_0/AIF_1956__6__1_0.pdf) it is.

Voisin's book mentioned by sweetjazz is indeed masterful but rather advanced.
Two good introductory, fairly reader friendly, books to that area are [Taylor's](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=i8lUNpZ379MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=joseph+taylor+several+complex&source=bl&ots=7MVqaXprex&sig=o63JAEz_sKc-2e63qxcSsIBYwcQ&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false)  textbook
and Wells's  classic [Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds](http://books.google.fr/books?id=a4Tptn3EPe4C&pg=PP1&dq=wells+differential+analysis&hl=fr&ei=SG2qTrylG4mj-gbOr4jPDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) .
The latter book culminates in the profound solution by Kodaira of Hodge's problem of characterizing the Kähler  complex manifolds underlying a projective algebraic variety.

Answer (score 7):

Transcendental Algebraic Geometry generally refers to algebraic geometry studied using techniques from the theory of complex variables, so that the results generally only apply to varieties defined over $\mathbb{C}$.  One of the basic references for this area is Claire Voisin's two volume series Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry.

Answer (score 5):

Griffith & Harris - "Principles of algebraic geometry" is also very good reference.

Answer (score 4):

There is also *Algebraic Geometry over the Complex Numbers* by Arapura.